# HTML text not aligning properly

Tags: html, css

I have a textbox and when I enter the term "laptop" its not visible properly. The problem is in IE9, not with Chrome.

[image]

HTML

```
<input id="small_search_string_sub" name="search_string" type="text" class="newsearch_sub rounded " placeholder="Search..." maxlength="500">
```

Here is the CSS:-

```
.newsearch_sub {
padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
background-color: #FFF;
width: 220px;
height: 25px;
margin-top: 10px;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: sniff out IE and handle it different from other browsers.

Comment: is the css a class applied to a text input? would be helpful to include relevant markup

Comment: Try to set a line-height value

Comment: Please include the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have no reset for the input default style, also the input has not format for the text on it, also the padding might be pushing down the text to far.

I tried this, and it seems to work well on IE9 for me, but the fact that I see another class (rounded) on the line of code that you send, makes me wonder if there is not something missing here, can you put a link to the code, even as a stand alone page, this way I can debug on ie9 on the proper code, and maybe give you a solution if this one does not work for you.

```
.newsearch_sub {
     padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
     background-color: #FFF;
     width: 220px;
     height: 25px;
     margin-top: 10px;
     vertical-align: top;
     font:12px/24px Arial,Helvetica
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone... The problem was with passing once i adjusted it fixed.. But yes when I run this code alone I don't have any problems, have issues only when I run with overall code..